# Enabling SOAP for PHP on CentOS 6.6 Server

Tags: centos6, soap

I am trying to enable SOAP on my server. Soap is installed, but doesn't show up in php_info.

PHP Version 5.4.39

System Info: Linux ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.secureserver.net 2.6.32-042stab106.4 #1 SMP Fri Mar 27 15:19:28 MSK 2015 x86_64

Configure Command:

```
 './configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

Loaded Configuration File: /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Which contains: [soap]

```
;extension=soap.so
; Enable soap extension module
extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so"
```

I am not sure what other information would be useful, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I run yum list installed, the php info is: 
php-common.x86_64 - 5.3.3-40.el6_6 - atsym updates
php-soap.x86_64  - 5.3.3-40.el6_6 -  atsym updates

Comment: Your question says you’re running PHP5.4 but those Yum packages are for PHP5.3.3. Has someone compiled PHP from source?

Answer (score 0):

`php-soap` is in EPEL, so I wouldn't bother with compiling it.

Install like this:

```
yum install epel-release
yum makecache
yum install php-soap
```

Comment: When I run install epel-release I get a message saing "Nothing to do". Running makecache I get "Metadata Cache Created". Running install php-soap I get "Nothing to do". php -m still doesn't show soap, nor does php_info();

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration command, you didn't compile with SOAP configuration.
Please try to compile your PHP by adding the option below:

```
--enable-soap=shared
```

So the full command for your compile should change to:

```
'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'--enable-soap=shared
```

Then, copy the compiled SOAP module by:

```
cp modules/soap.so /usr/lib64/php/modules
```

Restart your Apache web server with:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Then check if the SOAP extension is enabled from phpinfo() page.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing by using the command as follows.

```
yum install php54-php-soap
```